# How to get the recorded file generated while using Nuance Dragon Speech Recognition SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, speech-recognition

I am working on speech recognition functionality for which I used Nuance Dragon Speech recognition SDK.

I need the audio file which is recorded while speech recognition.

Is it possible to get this file?

If Yes, then How?